# UITabbar application problem

Tags: uitabbar

hello to every one
i am creating a tabbar application. it contains 5 tab. after pressing 2nd tab the view controller show the new View with contain only two new tab. 
i am completing first task of 5 tabbar view . now the question is how to show custom tabbar view?
if u have example please send me link.
thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to confuse your customers? If I tap on a `TabBar`-Icon I expect that they wouldn't change so that I can easily navigate between them. But nonetheless you can hide your current `TabBar` and create a new one at the same place (I mean a `TabBar` not a `TabBarController`. It would only look like a `TabBar` and you would have to set your logic on your own)